# jQuery Twitter like ticker. How To?

Tags: jquery, twitter, ticker

I have a working ticker, but I want the text to fade out to the left and right just like on the twitter wellcome page. any ideas how to realise that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter uses transparent (png) images with dark-to-transparent gradients to fade this text out. You can simply place them on top of your text.

Answer (score 0):

Just as previously mentioned twitter uses two png images with transparency. The code provided on the [jQuery WebTicker example page](http://jonmifsud.com/web-tools/jquery-webticker/) includes these fade-in and fade-out effects. The jQuery Plugins provides all the funcionality to create a twitter look-alike ticker all you would need to change is your list items and your CSS to match your template.